# Select columns with all zero entries in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, filter

Given a dataframe `df`, how to find out all the columns that only have 0 as the values?

```
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
0  0  0  0  1  0  0  1  0
1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1
```

Expected output

```
   2  4
0  0  0
1  0  0
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I'd simply compare the values to 0 and use `.all()`:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 2, (2, 8)))
>>> df
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
0  0  0  0  1  0  0  1  0
1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1
>>> df == 0
       0      1     2      3     4      5      6      7
0   True   True  True  False  True   True  False   True
1  False  False  True   True  True  False  False  False
>>> (df == 0).all()
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
4     True
5    False
6    False
7    False
dtype: bool
>>> df.columns[(df == 0).all()]
Int64Index([u'2', u'4'], dtype=int64)
>>> df.loc[:, (df == 0).all()]
   2  4
0  0  0
1  0  0
```

Comment: Since values are only `0` and `1`. You could use `df.loc[:, (~df.astype(bool)).all()]` too.

Comment: Another possible option: `df = df.loc[:, (df != 0).any()]`

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to `mask` the nonzero values and drop columns where all values are masked.

```py
df1 = df.mask(df != 0).dropna(axis=1)

# or filter the entire frame
df1 = df[df.eq(0)].dropna(axis=1)
```

[image: res]

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether all values are zeros by using the method [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html#pandas.DataFrame.any). It treats zero as `False` and other numbers as `True`:

```
df.any()
```

Output:

```
0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
4    False
5     True
6     True
7     True
dtype: bool
```

To select all zero columns use:

```
df.loc[:, ~df.any()]
```