# np.where on pd.DataFrame for dictionary of non-zero indicies

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, network-programming, where-clause

I'm trying to make a `nearest neighbors` thing that's super super fast.  Right now I'm using `networkx` then iterating through all the `G.nodes()` then  `S = set(G.neighbors(node))` then `S.remove(node)` which works pretty well but I want to get better at indexing and taking advantage of datastructures.  I'd like to move away from iterating when possible.

**I ultimately want to end of up with a dictionary object where key is root_node and value is a set of node neighbors (not including the root_node)**

Here's what my graph and `DF_adj` adjacency matrix looks like:
[image]

When I do `np.where(DF_adj == 1)` the output is 2 arrays that looks like:

```
(array([ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  2,  2,
        3,  3,  3,  4,  4,  4,  5,  5,  5,  6,  6,  6,  7,  7,  7,  8,  8,
        8,  9,  9, 10, 10]), array([ 0,  1,  3,  4,  5,  7,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  6,  8,  9, 10,  1,  2,
        0,  1,  3,  0,  1,  4,  0,  5,  6,  1,  5,  6,  0,  7,  8,  1,  7,
        8,  1,  9,  1, 10]))
```

Checked out this but it didn't help me completely
[Python pandas: select columns with all zero entries in dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16486762/python-pandas-select-columns-with-all-zero-entries-in-dataframe)

```
def neighbors(DF_adj):
    D_node_neighbors = defaultdict(set)
    DF_indexer = DF_adj.fillna(False).astype(bool) #Don't need this for my matrix but could be useful for non-binary matrices if someones needs it
    for node in DF_adj.columns:
        D_node_neighbors[node] = set(DF_adj.index[np.where(DF_adj[node] == 1)])
        D_node_neighbors[node].remove(node)
    return(D_node_neighbors)
```

**How can I use `np.where` on the entire `pd.DataFrame` to get this type of output?**

```
defaultdict(set,
            {'a': {'b', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'h'},
             'b': {'a', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'g', 'i', 'j', 'k'},
             'c': {'b'},
             'd': {'a', 'b'},
             'e': {'a', 'b'},
             'f': {'a', 'g'},
             'g': {'b', 'f'},
             'h': {'a', 'i'},
             'i': {'b', 'h'},
             'j': {'b'},
             'k': {'b'}})
```

Comment: You can't, `np.where()` ain't gonna return a dictionary.

Comment: I know but there might be a more efficient way that I'm thinking then iterating through all of the columns indvidually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with comprehension dict. If `df` is :

```
   a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j  k
a  1  1  0  1  1  1  0  1  0  0  0
b  1  1  1  1  1  0  1  0  1  1  1
c  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
d  1  1  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
e  1  1  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
f  1  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0
g  0  1  0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0
h  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  0
i  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  0
j  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0
k  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1
```

Then `{i:{ j for j in df.index if df.ix[i,j] and  i!= j} for i in df.index }` is :

```
{'j': {'b'},
 'e': {'a', 'b'},
 'g': {'b', 'f'},
 'k': {'b'},
 'a': {'b', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'h'},
 'c': {'b'},
 'i': {'b', 'h'},
 'f': {'a', 'g'},
 'b': {'a', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'g', 'i', 'j', 'k'},
 'd': {'a', 'b'},
 'h': {'a', 'i'}}
```

Or  2X faster:

```
s=df.index        
d=collections.defaultdict(set)
for (k,v) in zip(*where(df==1)): 
    if k!=v:
        d[s[k]].add(s[v])
```

Comment: `1 loop, best of 3: 4.75 s per loop
1 loop, best of 3: 2.41 s per loop` on my fastest one (the nx.graph) yours was twice as fast. Thanks man this is really helpful